Drawing/revealing svg lines sequentially on button click
I'm having the hardest time figuring this out. I had a version of this working to where the button click would cause the svg to draw line by line, but I can't get the sequencing to work properly. Whether it's actually drawn or simply masked then revealed, it's supposed to animate from the center out on each line. So the first set of lines would animate from the center out (left line draws down from right to left, right line draws down from left to right) and then the next line, and so on (like rungs of a ladder).
I attempted adding a mask to the svg defs but it just covered the whole image, where in my case I think it would have to be layered from the back (top line is the back most layer, it reveals for the next and so on)
How can I make this so that button click causes sequential drawing from the center out of each line, even if revealing the mask?


function animateSvg(){
        console.log('animating footer');


        let currentDrawLength = 0;
        
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          currentDrawLength += 10; 
          
          footerline1.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        
        topLineRight.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        topLineLeft.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        secondLineRight.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        secondLineLeft.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        thirdLineLeft.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        thirdLineRight.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        fourthLineRight.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;
        fourthLineLeft.style.strokeDasharray = `${currentDrawLength}, 3000`;

        });
    }, 10); 

       

    }
}
 <div>
 <button onclick="animateSvg()">Animate</button>
 </div>
 
 <svg  viewBox="0 0 758.57 337.81">
                <defs>
                    <style>
                    .newfootercls1 {
                        fill: none;
                        stroke: green;
                        stroke-linecap: square;
                        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
                        stroke-width: 23.8px;
                    }
                    </style>
                </defs>
                <path id="topLineRight"  class="newfootercls1" d="M381.22,12.6c14.3.44,29.45.94,30.7.94l-12.26-1.5c2.36,0,4.95-.3,7.28-.03,2.08.24,3.02,1.17,4.97,1.54,5.7,1.08,12.66-.05,18.47-.05,17.5,0,35,0,52.51,0,19.74,0,39.31,1.02,59.01,1.39,4.79.09,9.24,1.49,14.02,1.54,2.68.03,5.78-.51,8.4.03,3.97.82,8.32,4.68,11.55,6.88,3.74,2.54,6.2,5.18,9.38,8.36,4.39,4.39,9.92,7.61,13.85,12.46,1.65,2.04,2.36,3.74,2.94,6.21,1.52,6.39,5.13,11.72,8.74,17.24,3.01,4.6,5.11,9.51,7.8,14.28,2.67,4.74,6.14,8.8,8.66,13.65,3.61,6.95,8.33,12.29,13.02,18.55,5.73,7.65,10.65,15.86,16.39,23.5,5.34,7.11,8.98,15.31,13.71,22.84,4.31,6.86,8.91,13.66,13.02,20.64s7.07,14.29,11.67,20.55c3.72,5.06,8.81,9.82,13.07,14.48,4.52,4.93,7.99,10.11,11.58,15.77,3.8,6,8.11,11.53,11.65,17.71,4.28,7.47,8.57,14.94,12.61,22.54,2.29,4.3,2.69,12.16,2.7,17.09"/>
                <path id="topLineLeft" class="newfootercls1" d="M11.91,286.97c0-4.93,4.27-10.56,6.56-14.86,4.05-7.6,8.34-15.07,12.61-22.54,3.53-6.18,7.84-11.71,11.65-17.71,3.59-5.66,7.06-10.83,11.58-15.77,4.27-4.66,9.36-9.41,13.07-14.48,4.6-6.26,7.74-13.89,11.67-20.55,4.11-6.98,8.71-13.78,13.02-20.64,4.73-7.53,8.37-15.73,13.71-22.84,5.74-7.64,10.66-15.85,16.39-23.5,4.69-6.26,9.41-11.6,13.02-18.55,2.52-4.85,5.99-8.91,8.66-13.65,2.69-4.77,4.79-9.68,7.8-14.28,3.61-5.52,7.22-10.85,8.74-17.24.59-2.47,1.29-4.17,2.94-6.21,3.93-4.85,9.46-8.07,13.85-12.46,3.18-3.18,5.64-5.82,9.38-8.36,3.23-2.19,7.58-6.06,11.55-6.88,2.62-.54,5.72,0,8.4-.03,4.78-.05,9.23-1.45,14.02-1.54,19.7-.37,39.27-1.39,59.01-1.39,17.5,0,35,0,52.51,0,5.82,0,12.78,1.14,18.47.05,1.95-.37,2.89-1.3,4.97-1.54,1.1-.12,13.08.21,25.73.59"/>
                <path id="secondLineRight"  class="newfootercls1" d="M378.92,74.83c25.06.73,53.61,1.51,55.29.43,0,0-4.69,0,0,0,18.33.01,10.99,0,29.32,0,6.86,0,13.71.05,20.57-.03,5.58-.07,10.85,1.48,16.39,1.6,2.97.07,5.96-.4,8.89.21,9.14,1.89,17.67,6.32,23.72,13.25,3.96,4.54,8.26,8.94,12.4,13.32,3.12,3.29,5.41,7.06,8.27,10.57,7.73,9.47,14.82,19.88,21.08,30.45,4.39,7.41,8.11,15.17,12.64,22.49,5.84,9.44,11.28,20.06,18.07,28.81,5.62,7.26,9.76,15.31,14.41,23.26,7.04,12.03,14.28,23.66,22.44,34.98,6.67,9.25,12.92,18.72,19.3,28.16,4.92,7.28,13.14,14.47,11.65,23.91"/>
                <path id="secondLineLeft"  class="newfootercls1" d="M89.06,306.23c-1.49-9.43,6.73-16.62,11.65-23.91,6.38-9.44,12.63-18.92,19.3-28.16,8.16-11.31,15.4-22.95,22.44-34.98,4.66-7.96,8.79-16.01,14.41-23.26,6.79-8.76,12.23-19.37,18.07-28.81,4.53-7.32,8.25-15.08,12.64-22.49,6.26-10.57,13.36-20.98,21.08-30.45,2.86-3.51,5.15-7.27,8.27-10.57,4.14-4.38,8.44-8.78,12.4-13.32,6.05-6.94,14.58-11.37,23.72-13.25,2.93-.6,5.92-.14,8.89-.21,5.54-.12,10.81-1.67,16.39-1.6,6.86.09,13.71.03,20.57.03,18.33,0,10.99.01,29.32,0,4.69,0,8.59-.15,12.95-1.17,1.47-.35,18.59.19,37.76.75"/>
                <path id="thirdLineLeft"  class="newfootercls1" d="M381.22,132.42c-26.3,0-56.96,0-61.4,0-5.9,0-12.03-.49-17.9-.06-3.02.22-5.93,1.32-8.97,1.94-3.3.67-6.74.74-9.47,2.2-2.17,1.16-4.65,3.01-6.58,4.47-5.98,4.52-8.82,11.16-14.19,15.68-2.84,2.38-3.99,5.49-6.03,8.37-2.91,4.11-5.92,8.05-8.47,12.44-5.17,8.9-8.84,18.4-13.47,27.54-2.29,4.52-5.74,8.16-8.16,12.57-5.76,10.51-10.63,22.21-15.13,33.31-3.97,9.8-8.46,18.38-14.44,27.06-4.89,7.1-18.8,34.09-17.53,43.23"/>
                <path id="thirdLineRight"  class="newfootercls1" d="M578.38,317.03c1.27-9.14-8.07-31.99-12.96-39.08-5.98-8.67-10.47-17.25-14.44-27.06-4.5-11.1-9.37-22.8-15.13-33.31-2.42-4.41-5.87-8.05-8.16-12.57-4.63-9.14-8.3-18.64-13.47-27.54-2.55-4.39-5.56-8.32-8.47-12.44-2.04-2.88-3.19-5.99-6.03-8.37-5.37-4.51-8.21-11.15-14.19-15.68-1.93-1.46-4.41-3.31-6.58-4.47-2.72-1.45-6.17-1.53-9.47-2.2-3.04-.62-5.95-1.71-8.97-1.94-5.87-.43-12.01.06-17.9.06-7.62,0-15.24,0-22.87,0-3.18,0-19.74,0-38.54,0"/>
                <path id="fourthLineRight"  class="newfootercls1" d="M378.95,195.39c25.94-.12,51.45.02,55.27.02l-15.7-.8c7.82,0,16.53.19,23.52,2.54,3.82,1.29,7.21,2.52,9.5,6.08,2.99,4.66,4.92,10.38,7.56,15.3,5.14,9.56,11.6,17.28,14.57,28,2.37,8.53,6.51,15.55,10.15,23.52,1.27,2.77,1.77,5.83,3.08,8.56,1.39,2.89,3.62,5.66,5.22,8.41,4.96,8.54,7.97,28.36,7.6,38.44"/>
                <path id="fourthLineLeft"  class="newfootercls1" d="M262.68,324.92c-.37-10.08,2.68-29.36,7.63-37.9,1.6-2.75,3.83-5.52,5.22-8.41,1.31-2.73,1.82-5.79,3.08-8.56,3.64-7.98,7.78-15,10.15-23.52,2.98-10.73,9.44-18.44,14.57-28,2.64-4.92,4.57-10.63,7.56-15.3,2.29-3.57,5.68-4.8,9.5-6.08,3.58-1.21,31.3-1.63,58.54-1.76"/>
                </svg>
        </div>



